# UILabel's sizeToFit/sizeThatFits ignore the numberoflines property

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Problem: Determine the size (number of lines) a `UILabel` needs, assuming the width is 300 px. The string is longer, so I set the `lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` and invoked `sizeThatFits` to try to determine the size. But it gives a width of 457 px in a single line, rather than the expected 300px in two lines.

Please see:

```
CGSize available = CGSizeMake(300, INFINITY);
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)] autorelease];
label.text = title;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kBoldFont size:kTitleFontSize];
label.numberOfLines = 3;
CGSize sizedtoFit = [label sizeThatFits:available];
```

But I find that the sizedtoFit variable has a width of 457 pixels and a height of 22 px, and the UI displays a single line with clipped text. I expect a width of 300 pixels, and a height of 44 px for two lines.

The UILabel doc for numberoflines says:

When the receiver is resized using the `sizeToFit` method, resizing takes into account the value stored in this property. For example, if this property is set to 3, the `sizeToFit` method resizes the receiver so that it is big enough to display three lines of text.

I tried various combinations of:

1. Passing `CGRectZero` to the init function, passing 300x400 or 300 x infinity.
2. Setting the frame after creation rather than passing it to the `init` function.
3. Invoking `[sizeToFit]` and hoping it calculates the height assuming present width, but it doesn't.
4. Calling sizeToFit and then calling sizeThatFits`.
5. Invoking `layoutIfNeeded`.

None of them works. What am I doing wrong, or is this is bad bug where the documentation and the framework implementation don't agree? Thanks.

Comment: According to the doc, I believe it is a bug and I just reported it.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in iOS6 – [ sizeToFit] now takes numberOfLines into account.

Comment: @Pavel is right, just upgraded from 5.1 to 6.0 and magically `sizeToFit` returns the correct size (with increased height).

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem, size that fits simply ignores the size... /:
I ended up using:

```
CGRect textSize = [UILabel textRectForBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, CGFLOAT_MAX) 
                      limitedToNumberOfLines:3];
```

Works like a charm... :)

The documentation says you shouldn't call it directly, but i've been using it for a while, with approved submitted apps, and everything is just awesome... :)

Comment: I wouldn't be comfortable with doing that except as a last resort :)

Comment: care to elaborate on that @KartickVaddadi ? :)

Comment: Well, I don't want to do things the documentation says you shouldn't, except as a last resort.

Comment: Does this assume that you're using the default font?

Comment: The current documentation seems fine with using the instance method `CGRect textSize = [label textRectForBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, CGFLOAT_MAX) limitedToNumberOfLines:3]`. Note: this is not a class method as in @AlexZak's answer. Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILabel/textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:

Comment: `UITextView` has same bug in iOS 8, so I have to resort to your answer when comes with `UITextView`.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the `sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:` method?

For example:

```
CGSize sizeToFit = [title sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:label.frame.size lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: That was my fallback option, but the question is: why is sizeThatFits not working as it should? I was just told that if I set the numberOfLines to 0 (unlimited), it works.

Comment: This is no good if you want a maximum of three lines, like the question implied. Guess I need to calculate the height of three lines and pass it in to the sizeWithFont function then. Which sucks.

Comment: great answer. I found this the most useful for multiline labels. sizeWithFont is deprecated in iOS7, though. Have a look at my separate answer using boundingRectWithSize:

Answer (score 3):

I found Ian L's answer best using `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`, unfortunately sizeWithFont: is deprecated under iOS7.

This is how sizeWithFont: works **for a UILabel subclass** in iOS7:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedText.length); 
sizeToFit = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:self.bounds.size
                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin 
                                 attributes:[self.attributedText 
                          attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:&range] context:nil].size;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all deprecated.  Use boundingRectWithSize

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting unexpected results because you are not taking into consideration the  `UILabel`'s font. Try the following:

```
UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)] autorelease];
label.text = title;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kBoldFont size:kTitleFontSize];
label.numberOfLines = 0;

CGSize size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width,FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap ];
label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x,label.frame.origin.y,label.frame.size.width,size.height);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't limit the number of lines

Comment: In addition to not limiting the number of lines, it uses the NSString sizing method, which will ignore a ton of the additional capabilities of UILabel

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for ios5 for `sizeToFit`. You may use other solutions like `sizeWithFont` etc. In ios6, the issue is fixed. However, I have this workaround for my solutions:

```
int lineCount = myLabel.numberOfLines;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[myLabel sizeToFit];
myLabel.numberOfLines = lineCount;
```

And it works. Beware that for my situation, width of my label is fixed and I only need sizeToFit for adjusting height.