# Use sizeToFit with lineSpacing

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, sizetofit

I have a `UILabel` with several lines. The text is set dynamically, and my label height too, with this native method :

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

I have an other method that sets the line spacing in my label :

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My long dynamic text"];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:5];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];


myLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

The problem is that even if I set the line spacing first, and then call `sizeToFit`, the new height of my label is to small. It doesn't take in count the line spacing.

It really is a problem as my label is in a `UIScrollView` and I need the right height.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILabel's sizeToFit/sizeThatFits ignore the numberoflines property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041874/uilabels-sizetofit-sizethatfits-ignore-the-numberoflines-property)

Comment: No, my numberOfLines property is not ignored. It's set to 0 and works perfectly. I'm talking here about the line-height, line-spacing, call that how you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting size of label dynamically based on text length use this method:

```
/*! Returns the size of the label to display the text provided
    @param text
        The string to be displayed
    @param width
        The width required for displaying the string
    @param fontName
        The font name for the label
    @param fontSize
        The font size for the label
 */
- (CGSize)getSizeForText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)fontSize {
    CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    constraintSize.width = width;
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:attributesDictionary
                                      context:nil];

    CGSize stringSize = frame.size;
    return stringSize;
}
```

Comment: I guess that's the best answer... but I'm disappointed sizeToFit doesn't take in count the attributes. It' doesn't make any sens to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `– boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` method of the `NSMutableAttributedString`.  Refer the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3acontext%3a) for more info.