# UILabel won't resize

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uilabel, uitextview, sizetofit

I have UILabel in my View that should resize itself based on the content, but it doesn't do so. I have multiline content in it. I tried `[label sizeToFit]` +    `label.numberOfLines= 0`.

I don't have constraints for the UILabel.

I also tried to use UITextView instead, but there the font just stays on 13 and not as I want on 17. Can you help me?

This is the code that works now:

```
UILabel *textLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 158, self.view.bounds.size.width-40, 550)];
textLabel2.text = textString;
textLabel2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17];
textLabel2.numberOfLines = 0;
[textLabel2 sizeToFit];
[self.scroller addSubview:textLabel2];
```

Comment: look at the answer to the similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041874/uilabels-sizetofit-sizethatfits-ignore-the-numberoflines-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your `UILabel` programmatically:

This code first sets the `UIlabel`'s text then get the width of the text

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
//set label backgroundColor so you can see the label width changes according to text
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
//edit you label text
[label setText:@"very longgggg text"];

//get width of you text and set you font size to 17.0
CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]].width;

//set you label frame
label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, width, 30);

//add label to you view
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

If you're not creating you `UILabel` programmatically remove the `alloc init` line and connect you outlets to you xib or storyboard.

Comment: Worked! But I have one question! When I turn into landscape mode, there's a big hole on the right side. How can I update this so that the text goes to the right like I would make a constraint in the IB that says Trailing Space to Container?

Comment: Ok, I created the UILabel now programmatically. I'll attach the code into the question so that you see how my code is. My Problem is, when I use the app in Landscape mode, my text doesn't go until the whole width, it ends at about 3/4 of the view. how can I change this so that it goes until the end of the view?